# Why isn't Facebook's connect-js github project up-to-date?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to debug some odd behavior where the auth.logout event is being triggered even though the user isn't logged in.  I have a red-handed stacktrace of the event firing from FB.provide.setAuthResponse.  However, when I grep the connect-js source, I find that the string "setAuthResponse" doesn't even exist in the project.

Clearly the source code at https://github.com/facebook/connect-js is obsolete.  Why is this?  Given the extremely buggy nature of Facebook's API and SDK, how does FB expect us to get any work done without essential debugging tools?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Facebook has abandoned any pretense of platform support and now relies entirely on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that connect-js is deprecated. You should be using the javascript SDK for everything now. As a general rule of thumb with Facebook, if it's been around for 6 months it will probably be deprecated soon.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: As I understand it, the Javascript SDK is connect-js.  Or rather *was*.  If Facebook has decided to abandon the github source, where is the announcement?

Comment: I would agree it was connect-js. I think they more migrated to loading the js lib from their servers. Thus the latest update is always in place. Finding the "announcement" could be difficult. There is a lot documentation that is still available that has been deprecated. But you can't tell from the documentation.